# Numerically-Solving Coupled PDE-ODE System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, physics

I'm currently trying to simulate the dynamics of a particle with position $\mathbf{x}_a(t)$ which moves in response to a field $c$. The field is in turn influenced by the particle. The system is governed by the following equations:-

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} &= D_c \nabla^2 c -\beta c + h \delta(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_a(t) ) \tag{1}
\\[1em]
\frac{d\phi}{dt} &= -(\kappa/\gamma_R)\begin{pmatrix}-\sin \phi \\ \cos\phi\end{pmatrix}\cdot\nabla c \tag{2}
\\[1em]
\frac{d\mathbf{x}_a(t)}{dt} &= v\begin{pmatrix} \cos\phi \\ \sin\phi \end{pmatrix} \tag{3}
\end{align}

where $\mathbf{x}_a(t)$ is the position of some particle and $D_c, \beta, h, \kappa, \gamma_R$ and $v$ are all positive constants. I'm solving (1) at each time step using a finite difference scheme. Time-marching is handled using an operator-splitting method similar to that used here: https://www.dealii.org/current/doxygen/deal.II/step_19.html.

The results I get from my program don't agree with published data. There are a few tricky things that complicate the problem that I suspect are responsible -

1. Implementation of the Dirac delta in (1). The gradients of $c$ in (2) depend very sensitively on how the delta is implemented and on how the time-stepping is performed. To avoid a singularity in $c$, at timestep $n+1$ I evaluate gradients of $c$ at the $\mathbf{x}_a^{n}$ - that is to say, at the previous position of the particle.

When I do this, the gradients of $c$ I compute are very small ($\mathcal{O}(10^{-11}$) or smaller) and $\phi$ never changes. If I try to remedy this by artificially making the delta spike taller, gradients become too large and the observed behavior of the particle looks like a random walk (also not correct).

2. Another potential problem is that I can only evaluate the delta at grid points, meaning that in practice I simply have to find the grid point closest to $\mathbf{x}_a(t)$, evaluate the delta there and gradients of $c$ as well. I suspect this could also contribute to the apparent failure of my program.

Using finite elements is not an option at the moment. Is there any way to salvage this approach?

Comment: How is the delta function actually implemented? Is your finite difference scheme able to solve, e.g. $-\nabla^2 c = \delta(x-x_0)$ on a square to any degree of accuracy?

Comment: @whpowell96 No. However, I can get the correct order of convergence solving equations of the form $-\nabla^2u = f(x,y)$, assuming $f$ is sufficiently smooth. I'm not sure if the problem is (a) my implementation of the diffusion operator, (b) my implementation of the $\delta$, or (c) a fundamental limitation of finite difference methods

Comment: It is almost certainly the delta function causing issues. If you are forced to use finite differences, then the only ways forward I see would be to either use the integral conservation law to derive some jump conditions on the derivatives and try to impose those numerically, or to approximate the delta function with something smooth and use standard methods.

Comment: That's what I'm doing though - I'm approximating the delta as a thin Gaussian.